# Conditional expectation of a truncated distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X$  and $Z$ are two independent Normal random variables and $k$ is a constant. I am interested in the following conditional expected value
$$E(X|X<k<X+Z).$$

Since $X$  and $Z$ are Normally distributed, we know that $X+Z$ also follows a Normal distribution.

Comment: Notice $(X,Z)\sim f$ where $f(x,z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+z^2}{2}}$. You're looking to compute $$E(X|X<k<X+Z)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^k \int_{k-x}^\infty  xf(x,z)\mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}x}{\int_{-\infty}^k \int_{k-x}^\infty  f(x,z)\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x}$$

Comment: It is likely to be quicker by simulation: for example if $X$ and $Z$ are standard normal and $k=0$ then the conditional expectation is about $-0.467$